# How to Convert DataSet<Row> to DataSet of JSON messages to write to Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark 2.1.1.

I have the following `DataSet<Row>` ds1;

```
 name   | ratio | count  // column names
"hello" |  1.56 | 34
```

(`ds1.isStreaming` gives `true`)

and I am trying to generate `DataSet<String>` ds2. other words when I write to a kafka sink I want to write something like this

```
{"name": "hello", "ratio": 1.56, "count": 34}
```

I have tried something like this `df2.toJSON().writeStream().foreach(new KafkaSink()).start()` but then it gives the following error

```
Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()
```

There are `to_json` and `json_tuple` however  I am not sure how to leverage them here ?

---

I tried the following using `json_tuple()` function

```
 Dataset<String> df4 = df3.select(json_tuple(new Column("result"), " name", "ratio", "count")).as(Encoders.STRING());
```

and I get the following error:

> cannot resolve '`result`' given input columns: [name, ratio, count];;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `struct` function followed by `to_json` (as `toJSON` was broken for streaming datasets due to [SPARK-17029](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17029) that got fixed just [20 days ago](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/65accb813add9f58c1e9f1555863fe0bb1932ad8)).

---

Quoting the scaladoc of [struct](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@struct(colName:String,colNames:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

> **struct(colName: String, colNames: String*): Column** Creates a new struct column that composes multiple input columns.

Given you use Java API you have 4 different variants of [struct](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#struct(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) function, too:

> **public static Column struct(Column... cols)** Creates a new struct column.

With [to_json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_json(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) function your case is covered:

> **public static Column to_json(Column e)** Converts a column containing a StructType into a JSON string with the specified schema.

The following is a Scala code (translating it to Java is your home exercise):

```
val ds1 = Seq(("hello", 1.56, 34)).toDF("name", "ratio", "count")
val recordCol = to_json(struct("name", "ratio", "count")) as "record"
scala> ds1.select(recordCol).show(truncate = false)
+----------------------------------------+
|record                                  |
+----------------------------------------+
|{"name":"hello","ratio":1.56,"count":34}|
+----------------------------------------+
```

---

I've also given your solution a try (with Spark 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT built today) and it seems it works perfectly.

```
val fromKafka = spark.
  readStream.
  format("kafka").
  option("subscribe", "topic1").
  option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").
  load.
  select('value cast "string")
fromKafka.
  toJSON. // <-- JSON conversion
  writeStream.
  format("console"). // using console sink
  start
```

`format("kafka")` was added in [SPARK-19719](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19719) and is not available in 2.1.0.

Comment: A `List` of records?! `to_json` works with a single record so how is that possible? Please use gist.github.com and paste the whole code to review (as we might be talking about different things).

Comment: What if we need key with different name ?

Comment: @YashwanthKambala Care to elaborate? Can you show the input and output for a _"key with different name"_?

Comment: ```{"name":"hello","ratio":1.56,"count":34}``` , how can i get something like this    ``` {"Name":"hello","Ratio":1.56,"Actual_count":34}``` , without saving with column names as keys.

Comment: Wouldn't `from_json` and `map` work here? Please ask a separate question.

Comment: can you check my approach is correct , https://stackoverflow.com/a/57921825/3453912 . implemented in struct , not in Map

Comment: `from_json` is in 2.2.0 ? or only in newer versions.